# How to display an animated route over a city map using Jupyter/Python?

Tags: python, geolocation, data-visualization

I have a .csv file with a bunch of rows of timestamps, latitudes, and longitudes that represent a car driving around a city. I want to visualize this data in an animated time series of a car (or some icoon) driving around a city using Python. Are there any libraries for doing this?

All of the ones I have seen so far are on the country level with state borders drawn. I need a library where I can animate on a city map (specifically Philadelphia), with the zip code borders overlayed on the map as well.

Comment: For the animation part, maybe checkout [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org)